# Pandas: how to load a zip file containing multiple txt files?

Tags: python, csv, pandas, zip

I have many `zip` files stored in my path

- `mypath/data1.zip`
- `mypath/data2.zip`
- etc.

Each zip file contains three different `txt` files. For instance, in `data1.zip` there is:

- `data1_a.txt`
- `data1_b.txt`
- `data1_c.txt`

I need to load `datai_c.txt` from each zipped file (that is, `data1_c.txt`, `data2_c.txt`, `data3_c.txt`, etc)  and concatenate them into a dataframe.

Unfortunately I am unable to do so using `read_csv` because it only works with a single zipped file.

Any ideas how to do so? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So you need some other code to reach into the zip file. Below is modified code from O'Reilly's *Python Cookbook*

```
import zipfile
import pandas as pd
## make up some data for example
x = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2], "B": [3, 4]}) 
x.to_csv('a.txt', sep="|", index=False) 
(x * 2).to_csv('b.txt', sep="|", index=False)

with zipfile.ZipFile('zipfile.zip', 'w') as myzip:
    myzip.write('a.txt')
    myzip.write('b.txt')
    for filename in z.namelist( ): print 'File:', filename,
         insideDF = pd.read_csv(StringIO(z.read(filename)))
         df = pd.concat([df, insideDF])
print df
```

Comment: very sweet. Here nothing is written to the path, correct?

Comment: correct. It reads directly from the zip file. I do not know if behind the scenes Python uses temp files or what, but nothing gets left behind in the long run.

Comment: weird I get a long output like `0||||-8267.36|-8367.36||12.77|18.77|12.77|-8785.3|-8785.3|-8785.3||||1|
 does not exist` after specifying `sep='|'` in `read_csv`. Any ideas? The file names are read correctly though

Comment: might be due to the fact that `z.read()` returns a looooong string with the whole data...?

Comment: added a change to your answer

Comment: good catch.. I added some example data and made the full thing reproducible

Comment: This is a "legacy" Python 2 solution that won't work with the current Python 3. To make it work, add `from io import BytesIO` and replace the `StringIO` with `BytesIO`.

Answer (score 1):

You want to work with the [`patool`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/patool) library as follows:

```
import patool
import pandas as pd
compression = zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED
patoolib.extract_archive('mypath/data1.zip', outdir='mypath', interactive=False, verbosity=-1)
```

store eachtxt file in a `DataFrame` using `read_csv` as in:
    df = pd.read_csv('mypath/data1_a')

and then use [`pd.concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) to concatenate the dataframes in any way you want.

Comment: thanks but I do not want to extract the archive into the path. That would consume all of my disk space.

Comment: So you want to extract just some particular files from the archive?

Comment: I want everything to happen in memory (if that makes sense). I dont want to write anything on the folder

Comment: how large are the text files? because if they are really huge, you could just extract them one by one and delete each file immediately after you read it in as a dataframe.

Comment: not too large, but I dont have writing rights on that path